# Parse relational compound query with logical AND

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a chats class with a relations field for User.

In my database I've added two users to the user relation, userone and usertwo

```
var query = new Parse.Query("chats")
query.equalTo("Users",userone)
query.equalTo("Users",userthree)
```

What I expect is to get nothing, since my database only holds one chat with the users being userone and usertwo.

However what I get is the chat with both userone and usertwo. That implies my query is doing an OR query.

How do I query my chats class, making sure that the Users field must have 2 specific users?

Comment: Hmm.  Good one.  How about `query.equalTo("Users",[userone,userthree]);` ??  Shot in the dark.

Comment: That might work (return nothing) for your single-row of data just because its wrong.  To more thoroughly test, make sure it works for the positive case, with a chat between users one and three.